# JAXB :Class cast exception while trying to unmarshall XML using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

I am novice to JAXB , i am trying to sample using JAXB.

trying to dispaly the values in the MenuList.xml

----MenuList.xml-----------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<menulist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Category1 name="Development">
        <MenuItem1>Projects</MenuItem1>
        <MenuItem2>Library</MenuItem2>
        <MenuItem3>Library1</MenuItem3>
    </Category1>    
</menulist>
```

----------------------------MenuList.xsd-------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML Studio Developer Edition (Trial) 8.0.11.2171 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="menulist">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element  name="Category1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="MenuItem1" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="MenuItem2" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="MenuItem3" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

The uisng the command I run the xsd file and it generated the classes.
MenuList and Object Factory.

**AppTest.java**

```
package com.xx.menu;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class TestNew {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.xx.menu");        //Create unmarshaller
        Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        File file = new File ("C:\\sample\\menulist.xml");

        JAXBElement element = (JAXBElement)um.unmarshal(file);

        Menulist menulist= (Menulist) element.getValue ();
        System.out.println("name : "+menulist.getMenu());

        }
     catch( UnmarshalException ue ) {
         ue.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println( "Caught UnmarshalException" );
    } catch( JAXBException je ) { 
        je.printStackTrace();
    } catch( Exception ioe ) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xx.menu.Menulist
    at com.xx.menu.TestNew.main(TestNew.java:26)
```

---

Can you please help me where I am going wrong ...I will be greatly thankful to you.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're overcomplicating things. You don't need to muck about with `JAXBElement` if the `Unmarshaller` is giving you the `Menulist` object directly. The `ClassCastExcepotion` pretty much tells you what you need to do:

```
Menulist menulist= (Menulist) um.unmarshal(file);
```

`JAXBElement` is only used in certain specific situations, and this isn't one of them.

Comment: Could you please add a short description about when JAXBElement is to be used?

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please add a short description about when JAXBElement is to
>   be used?

`JAXBElement` is used by JAXB when a class or property does not contain enough information by itself to indicate what element should be written to XML.

**@XmlRootElement**

In your example the `Menulist` class corresponds to the `menulist` element.  Since in the schema that element has an anonymous complex type, one element is associated with the class generated from the corresponding complex type.

**@XmlElementDecl**

If in your example the `menulist` element had corresponded to a named complex type, then potentially multiple elements could correspond to the same class generated from that complex type.  Instead of annotating the class with `@XmlRootElement`, one or more `@XmlElementDecl` annotations would be generated on the `ObjectFactory` class.  This would cause `JAXBElement` to be unmarshalled.

**Handling All Results**

If you don't know whether or not a `JAXBElement` will be returned you can leverage a `JAXBIntrospector` to do any necessary unwrapping.

```
    JAXBIntrospector ji = jaxbContext.createJAXBIntrospector();
    Menulist menulist = (Menulist) ji.getValue(unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml));
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html